# Python import issue when running through pm2

Tags: python, node.js, linux, pm2

I have a node program called `Node Consumer` which executes the python code file using `PythonShell` library.
Node Consumer is started using `pm2`.

When the python code is executed , it gives a error `AttributeError: module 'arviz' has no attribute 'geweke'`

Now when the node program is started without pm2 , it works fine without any error

M running this on linux RHEL.

Please guide

Version Used :
Python 3.6
Nodejs 10

Comment: Compatibility issue, see [here](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/attributeerror-module-arviz-has-no-attribute-geweke/6818/21)

Comment: But it does not give an error if node program is started directly . It works fine without pm2

Answer (score 0):

The reason, I was facing this issue

- When the node program is started using pm2, python packages were accessed from the root(site packages) directory
- When the node program is started without pm2, python packages were accessed from the ec2-user(site packages) directory

It seems the package version was different in both the folders and that created the problem.

I just found the root cause , yet it be solved.

[image]